# Can I have an app that has a full fledged native version and a full fledged flutter version combined and interoperable? (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, repository, interop

So I have an Android native app and an iOS native app. Each have their own github repositories. They are both live. I've redesigned the entire app in Flutter. It also has it's own repo. Here's what I'm thinking of doing initially.

I want to merge the flutter version into the native apps as a sort of a Beta. So if the users go to the settings of the native app they are gonna have an option "Switch to new UI (Beta)" which will relaunch the app with the Flutter version. Once they are on the Flutter side they should be able to go to settings and select "Switch to Old UI" which will relaunch the app with the native version.

I have 3 questions here.

1. Is this possible in any way?
2. If yes, how do I keep the Flutter repository common so that I don't have to update the flutter code in each of the native repositories individually every time?
3. Is there anything else I should consider? (Like app size. I don't think our app size is more than 10mb in native android or flutter android)

(At some point when the flutter version is perfect I might get rid of the native code and switch to the Flutter UI completely)

Comment: I don't use Flutter, but it should be possible if you can compile the flutter part as a library instead of app. Then on the native side, you can use a SharedPreference to track the user's choice and in the entry point (launcher) activity, check the value to determine whether to open the native home activity or flutter home activity, and then immediately finish the entry point activity. For point 2 above, look into Git *submodules*.

Comment: IIRC, you'll want the entry point activity of your app to have the same class name and package through all versions of your app, or homescreen shortcuts will be broken. So if you follow my suggestion above, you need to rename what was your original home activity so you can use that name for the new switcher activity.

Comment: hey thanks a lot. I'll try that out. I just thought of this. Maybe I can add the iOS code and the android code to their respective Android/iOS folders in the flutter project itself. That should work right?

Comment: I don't know because I don't use Flutter. I don't know how it's structured.

Comment: Alright Thanks a lot. I'll try what you mentioned